# The `column` utility without the -t option

Tags: linux

After reading the man pages for `column` and trying a few examples, I wonder: what does this command do when it is **not** supplied the `-t` option?

Comment: so why not test it?

Comment: @KamilCuk I tested (as the question explicitly states), but obviously did not find the right test cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It takes lines and puts them on separate cell inside a table, filling rows first:

```
$ seq 40 | column
1   4   7   10  13  16  19  22  25  28  31  34  37  40
2   5   8   11  14  17  20  23  26  29  32  35  38
3   6   9   12  15  18  21  24  27  30  33  36  39
```

It's similar to `ls` output, but the separator is tab between columns, while `ls` uses spaces:

```
$ ls
a   ab  ad  af  ah  aj  al  an  ap  ar  at  av  ax  az  c  e  g  i  k  m  o  q  s  u  w  y
aa  ac  ae  ag  ai  ak  am  ao  aq  as  au  aw  ay  b   d  f  h  j  l  n  p  r  t  v  x  z
$ printf "%s\n" * | column
a   ac  af  ai  al  ao  ar  au  ax  b   e   h   k   n   q   t   w   z
aa  ad  ag  aj  am  ap  as  av  ay  c   f   i   l   o   r   u   x
ab  ae  ah  ak  an  aq  at  aw  az  d   g   j   m   p   s   v   y
```

If you have some newline-separated data that you want to represent in a condensed form in a nicely indented table, `column` is the way to go.